Issue with Elasticsearch Query for Subdomains
I have 200 million documents in Elasticsearch. Each document is structured as follows:
{"url": url,
"username": username}

Whenever I try to search for a specific domain like this:
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url": {
        "value": "*test.com*"
      }
    }
  }
}


It successfully returns URLs like:
{'url':'http://sd.test.com/login'}
{'url':'http://test.com/register'}
{'url':'http://admin.test.com:8080/'}


However, it doesn't return all subdomains. For example, the following URL is not included in the search results:
http://sds.test.com/User/Login
It only returns it when I change the query value to:
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url": {
        "value": "*test.com*/"
      }
    }
  }
}


But the others don't return with it :D
How can I modify my Elasticsearch query to consistently return all subdomains/domains for a specific domain without hardcoding each one? Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried using other query types such as match, query_string, and term, but none of them consistently return the desired subdomains.

How is the "URL" field defined in the mapping?

Maybe this answer helps you?
